# Change background color of inputs if checked or not

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write something that says, if the input checkbox is checked then change the correlating label's background color for that input box. If checked, should be red else all the others have their regular color. How can I uncheck the other inputs as I click on the other ones? All actual inputs are displayed as none, so I want to change the label's styling.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".main-container__checkbox").forEach((item) => {
  if (item.checked) {
    document.querySelectorAll(
      ".main-container__checkbox-label"
    ).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

obviously this just makes every labels background color red, but I cant figure out how to just make the one that is checked red

```
 <input
          id="main-checkbox-1"
          type="checkbox"
          class="main-container__checkbox"
          checked
        />
        <input
          id="main-checkbox-2"
          type="checkbox"
          class="main-container__checkbox"
        />
        <input
          id="main-checkbox-3"
          type="checkbox"
          class="main-container__checkbox"
        />

       
          <label for="main-checkbox-1" class="main-container__checkbox-label"
            >&nbsp;</label
          >
          <label for="main-checkbox-2" class="main-container__checkbox-label"
            >&nbsp;</label
          >
          <label for="main-checkbox-3" class="main-container__checkbox-label"
            >&nbsp;</label
          >
```

Answer (score 3):

If you rework your html to have the label wrap around the input - and then put the text in a span - after the input checkbox then you can achieve this with css alone - using the `:checked` pseudo-selector and the "`+`" direct sibling combinator.

This has the added advantage of being able to click the label text and toggle the checked state of the checkbox.

You could then take this one step further and hide the checkbox input and style the label to look like a button and you have a completely functional and valid toggle switch.

EDIT - noting that in the original post - you mention that the inpiuts are "display: none" then I have followed that and made these inputs act like toggle buttons.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  
}

label input {
 display: none;
}
.checkbox-label {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px #6e6e6e;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

input:checked + .checkbox-label {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p> click the following to toggle the hidden checkboxes - if the checkbox is checked - the label background will be red <p>

<label>
   <input
    id="main-checkbox-1"
    type="checkbox"
    class="main-container__checkbox"
    checked
    />
    <span class="checkbox-label">main-checkbox-1</span>
 </label>
  
 <label>
   <input
    id="main-checkbox-2"
    type="checkbox"
    class="main-container__checkbox"
    />
    <span class="checkbox-label">main-checkbox-2</span>
 </label>
 
  <label>
   <input
    id="main-checkbox-3"
    type="checkbox"
    class="main-container__checkbox"
    />
    <span class="checkbox-label">main-checkbox-3</span>
 </label>
```

Comment: Thank you for the good answer, but I think do need it in javascript because I need only one input able to be checked at a time and also want to display different content in the html depending on what input is checked. Would you be able to solve this in js only?

Comment: if only one input a t a time can be selectoed - then what you need is a radio button grounp not a checkbox groupo - the fundamental difference between a radio button and a checkbox is that only one radiobutton at a time can be selected- whereas multiple checkboxes can be selected at a time. and you can creat e this still with css - and have different selectors give different background colors. CSS is always preferable if possible for performance.

Comment: Thats why this is so hard for me to figure out, im using checkboxes instead of radio buttons... completely forgot about them and am trying to solve this using checkboxes, I've been losing my mind. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can achieve the same using event listener. Have added inline comments for easy understanding

```js
// getting all the checkbox , iterating to add event listener 
document.querySelectorAll(".main-container__checkbox").forEach((item) => {
  // calling the function to pass the current element under iteration
  addBackGround(item);
  // adding event listener to the checkbox so on change it will add/remove the background color
  item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // e is event object, e.target is the element on which any event occured
    addBackGround(e.target)
  })

})
// a function which will add the back ground color
function addBackGround(item) {
  // getting the id of the element 
  const elemId = item.getAttribute('id');
  // finding the label using attribute selector
  const labelElement = `label[for=${elemId}]`;
  // if checkbox is checked then add background color
  if (item.checked) {
    document.querySelector(labelElement).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(labelElement).style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="main-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" class="main-container__checkbox" checked />
<label for="main-checkbox-1" class="main-container__checkbox-label">
main-checkbox-1
</label>
<input id="main-checkbox-2" type="checkbox" class="main-container__checkbox" />
<label for="main-checkbox-2" class="main-container__checkbox-label">main-checkbox-</label>
<input id="main-checkbox-3" type="checkbox" class="main-container__checkbox" />
<label for="main-checkbox-3" class="main-container__checkbox-label">main-checkbox-3</label>
```